# cs0029 cannot implicity convert type float to unityengine3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class platform : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] float objectSpeed = 1;
    private float resetPosition = -21.67f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * (objectSpeed* Time.deltaTime));
        if (transform.localPosition = resetPosition) {
            Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(120, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            transform.position = NewPos;

        }
    }
}
```

i want a tile to respawn after it reaches this particular location

Comment: Please add more description to the question

Answer (score 1):

You missed one equal (`=`) sign in your comparison. Additionally, you are comparing a `Vector3` object with a `float` object which is technically not possible. You can compare a side of your vector (such as `x` or `y`) with your `resetPosition`. From your code, I can  guess that you want your object to get back in starting position once it passes your reset position. To achieve this, you would have to compare your local object and see if it passes that specific point of your vector's side.

```cs
if (transform.localPosition.x >= resetPosition) {
..
}
```

However, this is not the best approach. Idiomatic way to write this code is to make your variable a `Vector3`, since you have already named it a "position". Moreover, you can compare each side of your vectors using simple comparison operators or by using the [Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) method.

Comment: @ArmaanQadri Did you change `transform.localPosition` to `transform.localPosition.x`?

Comment: @ArmaanQadri Also, change `==` sign to `>=`, I am assuming that you want to reset your object back to it's starting position; Floating point numbers are precise and using equal operator on two floating point numbers will check precisely if both numbers are equal.